# What does the return do at the end of the expression of a PHP condition?

Tags: php, if-statement, return, operators

I am analyzing a PHP code but I cannot understand the logic of a condition with a return at the end.

```
Route::domain('{name}.{domain}.{tls}')->group(function () {
    $settings = App::make(\Common\Settings\Settings::class);
    $appUrl = config('app.url');
    $currentUrl = \Request::url();
    if ($appUrl === $currentUrl || !$settings->get('builder.enable_subdomains')) return; //<- Here
    Route::get('{page?}', 'UserSiteController@show')->name('user-site-subdomain');
});
```

I need to understand what are the circumstances that line 6 will be executed but apparently the return changes everything.

Any clarification or some more illustrative example will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It immediately ends this function to prevent

`Route::get('{page?}', 'UserSiteController@show')->name('user-site-subdomain');`

from being executed if conditions in

`if ($appUrl === $currentUrl || !$settings->get('builder.enable_subdomains'))`

are met (`$appUrl === $currentUrl` **or** `!$settings->get('builder.enable_subdomains')` equals true). Just like you would end a function normally with for e.g. `return 4;`, but you do not return any value.

Comment: It is just what I needed to understand, now I find more logic to the behavior of the code. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It returns something to the function which calls it.